# ArcMap 10.3.1-Attribute Table Sorting Issues

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, attribute-table, arcgis-10.3, sorting

I have received a shapefile from a third party that contains a column of alphanumeric characters. ArcMap has it listed as a 'string' in the field properties. The numbers range from 1-6000 with a combination of letters after the numbers. So it looks like:

```
1
10
100
1000
1001
```

Then the list continues in a random order and it includes letters at the end such as:

```
1387a
6176b
```

I'm trying to find a way to sort this properly? Would I be best splitting it and then sorting and concatenating it again? Is there any easier way to sort this column?

Comment: split numeric and letter part in two news columns and create advanced ordering on this new column

Comment: Please **edit** the question to clarify whether the table is in "random order" or just lexical order for ASCII text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want understand how it work.
[a-z] is ordering after [0-9] and text is ordering by left to right position

In fact, if you don't split you have (in ascending)

```
- 600
- 609
- 6000
- 6001
- 6009
- 600A
- 602B
- 603Z
- 69Z
```

After splitting, you have (in ascending with same ids)

```
- 69, "Z"
- 600, ""
- 600, "A"
- 602, "B"
- 603, "Z"   
- 609, ""
- 6000, ""
- 6001, ""
- 6009, ""
```

Also, if you need ordering with separate number and text part you can create 2 new columns. 1st content numeric part. 2nd content letter part.

[image]

Ordering is not persistent

**If you need a persistent ordering, you need create New FeatureClass but it's useless. Or fix your id column with fixed len char**

So, if you need ordering in one column and fix position you can add "-" after all ids if this id doesn't end by letter (and if you add only one ending letter)
and add 0 before number to have a fixed len char based on max character contains on id

```
- 0069Z
- 0600-
- 0600A
- 0602B
- 0603Z  
- 0609-
- 6000-
- 6001-
- 6009-
```